# Wrong positioning of D3 nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a simple force layout that calculates nodes and links when certain buttons are clicked.  The first time the nodes are calculated and displayed everything is correctly positioned. However, when nodes are recalculated after another click, the position of the circles I have appended to the nodes are way off yet the text I added remains in the right place.  Here's my JS:

```
  //Compute Nodes and Links
  var data = this.computePreviewNodes($(e.currentTarget).data("id"), $(e.currentTarget).data("type"));

  var canvas = d3.select(".body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", screen.height/2)
            .append("g");

        canvas.append("text")
            .text(compObj.name)
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("font-size", "2em")
            .attr("x", width/2)
            .attr("y", 40);

        var force = d3.layout.force()
            .nodes(data.nodes)
            .links(data.links)
            .gravity(.05)
            .distance(100)
            .charge(-10)
            .size([width, screen.height/2]);

        var links = canvas.selectAll(".links")
            .data(data.links)
            .enter().append("line")
                .attr("class", "links")
                .attr("fill", "none")
                .attr("stroke", "blue");

        var nodes = canvas.selectAll(".nodes")
            .data(data.nodes)
            .enter()
                .append("g")
                .attr("class", "nodes")
                .call(force.drag);

        nodes.append("circle")
            .attr("cx", function(d) {return d.x;})
            .attr("cy", function(d) {return d.y;})
            .attr("r", 10)
            .attr("fill", "green");

        nodes.append("text")
            .text(function(d) {return d.name})
            .attr("text-anchor", "right")
            .attr("font-size", "1.8em")
            .attr("y", 5);

        force.on("tick", function(e) {
            nodes
                .attr("transform", function(d, i){
                    return "translate(" + d.x + ", " + d.y + ")";
                });

            links
                .attr("x1", function(d) {return d.source.x;})
                .attr("y1", function(d) {return d.source.y;})
                .attr("x2", function(d) {return d.target.x;})
                .attr("y2", function(d) {return d.target.y;})
        })
        force.start();
```

My computePreviewNodes() function simply comes up with what nodes need to be displayed based on which button is clicked.  My thoughts are that maybe I'm not updating my node positions correctly after the second rendering of my nodes.  Any ideas?

Here's my canvas at the first click:
[image: correct]

And here it is when I click/calculate my nodes once again:
[image: wrong]

Comment: is there any more code to go with this ? Put a JSFiddle together and we can edit the code easily :)

Comment: I'll get right on it

Comment: shouldn't be too difficult to fix, looks like your translating the nodes incorrectly on the click, we'll see ...